# Execute stored procedure from a Trigger after a time delay

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, sql-server-express

I want to call stored procedure from a trigger,
how to execute that stored procedure after x minutes?
I'm looking for something other than `WAITFOR DELAY`

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have an SQL Agent job that runs regularly and pulls stored procedure parameters from a table - the rows should indicate also when their run of the stored procedure should occur, so the SQL Agent job will only pick rows that are due/slightly overdue. It should delete the rows or mark them after calling the stored procedure.

Then, in the trigger, just insert a new row into this same table.

You *do not* want to be putting anything in a trigger that will affect the execution of the original transaction in any way - you definitely don't want to be causing any delays, or interacting with anything outside of the same database.

---

E.g., if the stored procedure is

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoMagic
    @Name varchar(20),
    @Thing int
AS
  ...
```

Then we'd create a table:

```
CREATE TABLE MagicDue (
    MagicID int IDENTITY(1,1) not null, --May not be needed if other columns uniquely identify
    Name varchar(20) not null,
    Thing int not null,
    DoMagicAt datetime not null
)
```

And the SQL Agent job would do:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * from MagicDue where DoMagicAt < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Name varchar(20)
    DECLARE @Thing int
    DECLARE @MagicID int

    SELECT TOP 1 @Name = Name,@Thing = Thing,@MagicID = MagicID from MagicDue where DoMagicAt < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

    EXEC DoMagic @Name,@Thing

    DELETE FROM MagicDue where MagicID = @MagicID
END
```

And the trigger would just have:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Xyz ON TabY after insert
AS
    /*Do stuff, maybe calculate some values, or just a direct insert?*/
    insert into MagicDue (Name,Thing,DoMagicAt)
    select YName,YThing+1,DATEADD(minute,30,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) from inserted
```

---

If you're running in an edition that doesn't support agent, then you may have to fake it. What I've done in the past is to create a stored procedure that contains the "poor mans agent jobs", something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DoBackgroundTask
AS

     WHILE 1=1
     BEGIN
         /* Add whatever SQL you would have put in an agent job here */

         WAITFOR DELAY '00:05:00'
     END
```

Then, create a second stored procedure, this time in the `master` database, which waits 30 seconds and then calls the first procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BootstrapBackgroundTask
AS
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:30'
    EXEC YourDB..DoBackgroundTask
```

And then, mark this procedure as a startup procedure, using [`sp_procoption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181720.aspx):

```
EXEC sp_procoption N'BootstrapBackgroundTask', 'startup', 'on'
```

And restart the service - you'll now have a continuously running query.

Comment: Sorry if forget to add sql-express tag.

Comment: @MohammedRabee - Something's wrong with your tagging then - There is no SQL Server 2000 Express. There was MSDE, but the first express edition was 2005. Can you correct please?

Comment: I want this to work on sql-server2000 and sql-server2008express

Comment: @MohammedRabee - I've added a third section to my answer with a way to create a simple scheduled task when Agent isn't available.

Answer (score 1):

I had kind of a similar situation where before I processed the records inserted into the table with the trigger, I wanted to make sure all the relevant related data in relational tables was also there.

My solution was to create a scratch table which was populated by the insert trigger on the first table.

The scratch table had a updated flag, (default set to 0), and an insert `get date()` date field, and the relevant identifier from the main table.

I then created a scheduled process to loop over the scratch table and perform whatever process I wanted to perform against each record individually, and updating the 'updated flag' as each record was processed.

BUT, here is where I was a wee bit clever, in the loop over process looking for records in the scratch table that had a `update flag = 0`, I also added the `AND` clause of `AND datediff(mi, Updated_Date, getdate())> 5`. So the record would not actually be processed until 5 minutes AFTER it was inserted into the scratch table.