# Set Scheduled Time For Trigger

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core

I Want Sync two database at specified time with this trigger
 ,
but i want set scheduled time ,
for example sync two database at 11:00 PM every day .
how to set time for this trigger ?

```
 create trigger addMyTable
on myTable
after insert
as
insert into myTable2(myid,myName,myAge,gender)
select myid,myName,myAge,gender from inserted
go

create trigger deleteMyTable
on myTable
for delete
as
delete from myTable2 where myid in (select deleted.myid from deleted)
go


create trigger updateMyTable
on myTable
for update
as
begin
    delete from myTable2 where myid in (select deleted.myid from deleted)
    insert into myTable2(myid,myName,myAge,gender) select myid,myName,myAge,gender from inserted
end
go
```

Comment: For this type of scenario you don't need trigger, you need a SQL Job

Comment: i upload my web site in host, but host sql server is not supported job ,

Comment: Is there another way?

Comment: what about a windows service, or a console app which you can schedule??

Comment: i want perform it without job , is there another way ?

Comment: something have to invoke the process at 11:00 PM, without any scheduled event how do you expect it to happen automatically?

Comment: well , how can  i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute stored procedure from a Trigger after a time delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240247/execute-stored-procedure-from-a-trigger-after-a-time-delay)

Comment: thanks,but its run every 30 seconds but i want sync at specified time.
can is use it in asp.net core ?